# clearing text from cells in table for every even td

Tags: jquery, html, css

this issue has driven me mad, I've tried numbers of approaches using jquery and CSS but honestly nothing good came out of it, basically i have this following table:

```
<table id="mainTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Arrival Hours</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>19:30<span></td>
      <td>Mike</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>20:00<span></td>
      <td>eric</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>20:30<span></td>
      <td>jonas</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

i need the hide the even spans basically here which is `20:00`, table above is an example, the table that i am working with is made by data dynamically, so i thought maybe this works made a class like below:

```
.scale-draft:nth-child(2n){
    display: none !important;
}
```

but it did not work, tried this script as well:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mainTable tbody tr td:nth-child(2n)').css('visibility','hidden');
    });
```

yet another failure, i am bit confused at the moment, can you help me out?

Comment: so you just want to hide all the spans tag of the table?

Comment: @chiller nope mate, i just want to hide `even` spans like: 2nd, 4th, 6th ...

Comment: `tr:nth-child(even) td span { display: none; }`? Or `visibility: hidden;`?

Comment: @DavidThomas let me test it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```css
tr:nth-child(even) td span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="mainTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Arrival Hours</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>19:30</span>
      </td>
      <td>Mike</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>20:00</span>
      </td>
      <td>eric</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>20:30</span>
      </td>
      <td>jonas</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The reason your jQuery selector didn't retrieve the elements you *seem* to want to collect is because:

```
#mainTable tbody tr td:nth-child(2n)
```

`:nth-child()` selects an element based on its position within its parent, rather than its position with the ancestor `<table>`, or `<tbody>`, element.

My suggested approach selects the even `<tr>` rows within the `<tbody>` element, and then styles the `<span>` elements within the `<td>` elements found within those `<tr>` elements.

Incidentally, your posted HTML had some errors – corrected in this answer – none of your `<span>` elements were closed. This didn't, in this case, affect the problem, but it remains invalid HTML:

> Tag omission in text/html:
>   Neither [the opening or closing] tag is omissible

<sub>https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element</sub>

The problem with invalid HTML is that the browser will try to 'rescue' it, making it valid, when constructing the DOM which is often implementation-specific, so each browser may correct the DOM differently, leading to cross-browser issues with JavaScript and CSS.

Further, it's worth noting that the above solution will hide *all* `<span>` elements in the even rows, if you wish to hide the `<span>` elements in only the first cell, you may wish to amend the selector to:

```
tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child span {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="mainTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Arrival Hours</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>19:30</span>
      </td>
      <td>Mike</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>20:00</span>
      </td>
      <td>eric</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>20:30</span>
      </td>
      <td>jonas</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't require to write JS for this, I notice that the `span` tag is not closed in your HTML and use the following code :

HTML:

```
<table id="mainTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Arrival Hours</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><span>19:30</span></td>
      <td>Mike</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span>20:00</span></td>
      <td>eric</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span>20:30</span></td>
      <td>jonas</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#mainTable tr td:nth-child(2n){
    display: none !important;
}
```

DEMO : 
https://jsfiddle.net/zrnvozhk/